# Android Studio How to push to new Repository

Tags: android, github, repository, bitbucket

Hi I have recently made a project in android studio and just want to push it to a repository. I've pulled before but never pushed a brand new one and haven't found a good tutorial as to do so. Whenever I push it will make a Repository folder on Github or Bitbucket but never push any files.

Comment: you wanted to push to github or bitbucket

Comment: That's not so much an android question. Seems like you need to study some git basics.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1)Create a repository in bitbucket/github.

2)You would get a link like `https://blah blah@bitbucket.org/.../....git`

3)Now create the project in Android Studio.On the top menu, select `VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository.`

4)After creating it open terminal inside the Studio itself and add a origin u want to push using the following git command `git remote add origin https://blah blah@bitbucket.org/.../....git`

5)NOw, right click your projects root directory and select `Git > Add`. This will add all your project files to your Git repository.After adding right click the project name again and this time select `Git > Commit` Directory.After entering the commit message then finally commit

6)Then finally push it by  selecting `Git > Repository > Push.`

Comment: Probably should add.. one needs to download the Bitbucket Plugin from JetBrains via initial Android Studio startup screen. (It wasn't included in my Linux version of Android Studio)

Comment: In android studio 1.3 i also had to restart android studio. Otherwise it wouldn't allow me to add files

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying Git>Add in your projects root directory, say

```
git add --all
```

in command prompt